# netbeans projects that depends on other projects and their includes

Tags: c++, netbeans, dependencies, projects-and-solutions, include-path

I have a certain c++ (library) project in netbeans 7.0. Lets call it the A project.

Now i have a c++ (application) project called B.

B depends on A:

1) at compile-time for some includes in A project

2) at link-time for the libA.so

2) is pretty easy, since i just need to go to project properties-> build(linker) -> libraries and click "Add Project.."

However its not that clear what the best nice, clever approach for 1) is. I've created pkg-config entries in the past to help projects find third-party libraries, but is a bit more work to do it for projects themselves. I could also include existing file directly, but i would have to add ugly ../../A/ in the includes which is **PRECISELY** what i'm trying to avoid

So I would like to hear about people solving this problem in the past and what was the best solution they found

Answer (score 0):

You can add "an additional library directory" in the linker portion of the project properties. Then you can refer to library file "A" without the path specifier. This is a command line option to the linker to search that directory for libraries it has not found.

I'm not sure if they've added that option to the project properties for Qt projects in 7.0 or not. It's missing for those projects in 6.9.1

Comment: yes, that would be item 2) which is covered. I'm wondering about item 1) (includes)